# How to add Items to JList from another window

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, jlist

I have 2 windows. one got an empty JList and the other one got a button.  So I want to add the value to the list whenever I press the button.  Here is my code but not completed:

**Window 1**

```
final DefaultListModel<String> favouriteNames = new DefaultListModel<String>();
JList namesList = new JList(favouriteNames);
```

**Window 2**

```
public class button extends JFrame {

private JList namesList;
private DefaultListModel<String> favouriteNames;

this.namesList = namesList;

 JButton addThis = new JButton("Add");
 addThis.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          favouriteNames.addElement("Jack");
   }
 });
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Pass an instance of your DefaultListModel to Window 2 in the constructor.

Edited to add: Here's how you pass an instance in a constructor.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ButtonFrame implements Runnable {

    private JFrame              frame;

    private DefaultListModel    favouriteNames;

    public ButtonFrame(final DefaultListModel favouriteNames) {
        this.favouriteNames = favouriteNames;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton addThis = new JButton("Add");
        addThis.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                favouriteNames.addElement("Jack");
            }
        });

        frame.add(addThis);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ButtonFrame(new DefaultListModel()));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.  Not sure how to do it but here is my idea and the error: `Window1 favouriteNames;` and in the action listener I get addElement gets highlighted and this is the error: The method addElement(String) is undefined for the type Frame.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and time. But it doesn't work. Nothing happens when I press the button. Not any error, but not adding to the list.

Comment: BTW should I edit window 1? the class that the actual list is located.

Comment: @AlexJj: You really shouldn't have 2 windows at all.  I'm extremely frustrated by the sheer number of beginners that want to do extremely complicated GUI's right away without taking the time to learn the basics.

Comment: Well the program that I am working on is bigger than this example something with 4 different classes. so I just simplified it to smaller pieces to make it easier. And all point of my question is to pass the variables and control components from different classes classes.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simpler version of my program, but still have a problem, I believe the ActionPerformed sends the data but the JList does not recognise it or or basically did not expect to receive it.  So here is what I have done so far.  So it is a bit more of my research and attempts, maybe it gives more details about the problem.

Main Window:

```
public class main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFrame frame = new ClassA();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

ClassA:

```
public class ClassA extends JFrame {

        DefaultListModel<String> myList;
        JList list;

        public ClassA() {

        setSize(300,200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));

        myList = new DefaultListModel<String>();
        list = new JList(myList);


        //ClassB sendsText = new ClassB(myList, list);

        JButton find = new JButton("Find");
        find.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new ClassB().setVisible(true);
            }

        });


        add(panel);
        panel.add(find);
        panel.add(list);
    }

}
```

ClassB:

```
public class ClassB extends JFrame {

    DefaultListModel<String> myList;
    JList list;
    public ClassB(DefaultListModel<String> myList, JList list){
        this.myList = myList;
        this.list = list;
    }


    public ClassB() {
        setSize(300,200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));

        JButton addMe = new JButton("Add Me");
        addMe.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                myList.addElement("Danial");

            }

        });

        add(panel);
        panel.add(addMe);
    }

}
```